# How to use two script manager in single aspx page?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a issue with my `aspx` page regarding to `ScriptManager`.

If I use single script manager then it shows error

> Control 'maincontent_ctl00' of type 'ScriptManager' must be placed inside a form tag with runat=server.

If I use `ScriptManager` inside the form tag then it shows

> Only one instance of a ScriptManager can be added to the page

If i I use singles script manager then issue if I use two then still issue.

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="chat.aspx.cs" Inherits="ChatManager.chat" MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback="true" ValidateRequest="false" %>

 <asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="maincontent" runat="server">
 <script>
        function playSound() {
         document.getElementById("audioId").play();
     }
</script>

<audio id="audioId" src="Sound/tone.wav" style="display: none" controls="controls" preload="auto"></audio>
     <asp:ScriptManager runat ="server" ></asp:ScriptManager>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" Interval="3000" 
   OnTick="Timer1_Tick">
        </asp:Timer>
        <asp:Panel ID="Panel2" runat="server">
            <div>
                <h5 class="alert alert-success" style="text-align: center">
                      <span>Hello 
       <%=Server.HtmlEncode(CurrentSender.Text).ToUpper()%> !!</span>
                    <asp:Button ID="Logout" runat="server" Text="logout" 
     OnClick="logout_Click" CssClass="btn btn-warning" Height="30px" />
                </h5>
            </div>
        </asp:Panel>
        <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server">
            <div style="max-height: 520px; padding: 5px" class="col-lg-12 pre-scrollable">
                <asp:Label ID="CurrentSender" runat="server" Text="" Visible="false"></asp:Label>
                <asp:Label ID="CurrentRecevier" runat="server" Text="" Visible="false"></asp:Label>

                <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource3" runat="server" ConnectionString='<%$ ConnectionStrings:RegistrationConnectionString %>' SelectCommand="SELECT [MsgSender] FROM [MsgTable] WHERE (([RecevierSeen] = 0) AND ([MsgReceiver] = @MsgReceiver))">
                    <SelectParameters>
                        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="CurrentSender" PropertyName="Text" Name="MsgReceiver" Type="String"></asp:ControlParameter>
                    </SelectParameters>
                </asp:SqlDataSource>
                <div class="panel panel-danger">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <span>Unread Messages </span>
                        <span>
                            <asp:Label ID="UnreadMsgCountLabel" runat="server" CssClass="badge"></asp:Label>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="list-group">
                        <asp:DataList ID="DataList4" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource3" Width="100%">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:LinkButton Text='<%# Eval("MsgSender") %>' runat="server" ID="MsgSenderLabel" OnClick="UsernameLabel_Click" CssClass="list-group-item" />
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:DataList>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString='<%$ ConnectionStrings:RegistrationConnectionString %>' SelectCommand="SELECT [Username] FROM [UserDatabase] WHERE ([Username] <> @Username) AND OnlineStatus = 1">
                    <SelectParameters>
                        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="CurrentSender" PropertyName="Text" Name="Username" Type="String"></asp:ControlParameter>
                    </SelectParameters>
                </asp:SqlDataSource>
                <div class="panel panel-success">
                    <div class="panel-heading">Online Users</div>
                    <asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" Width="100%">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <div class="list-group-item">
                                <asp:LinkButton Text='<%# Eval("Username") %>' runat="server" ID="UsernameLabel" OnClick="UsernameLabel_Click" CssClass=" " />
                                <div class="OnlineCSS" />
                            </div>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:DataList>
                </div>

                <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" ConnectionString='<%$ ConnectionStrings:RegistrationConnectionString %>' SelectCommand="SELECT [Username] FROM [UserDatabase] WHERE ([Username] <> @Username) AND (OnlineStatus = 0  or OnlineStatus is null)">
                    <SelectParameters>
                        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="CurrentSender" PropertyName="Text" Name="Username" Type="String"></asp:ControlParameter>
                    </SelectParameters>
                </asp:SqlDataSource>
                <div class="panel panel-info">
                    <div class="panel-heading">Offline Users</div>
                    <asp:DataList ID="DataList3" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" Width="100%">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <div class="list-group-item">
                                <asp:LinkButton Text='<%# Eval("Username") %>' runat="server" ID="UsernameLabel" OnClick="UsernameLabel_Click" />
                                <div class="OfflineCSS"></div>
                            </div>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:DataList>
                </div>
            </div>
        </asp:Panel>
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger EventName="Tick" ControlID="Timer1" />
    </Triggers>

</asp:UpdatePanel>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <div>

            <h4 style="text-align: center" class="alert alert-info"><%= GetWelcomeBanner(CurrentRecevier.Text)%></h4>
            <span style="float: right"></span>
        </div>
        <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="chatPanel">
            <div style="vertical-align: middle; min-height: 480px;" class="pre-scrollable">
                <div>
                    <asp:DataList ID="DataList2" runat="server" Font-Bold="False" Font-Italic="False" Font-Overline="False" Font-Strikeout="False" Font-Underline="False" HorizontalAlign="Center" RepeatLayout="Table">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <div class="<%#GetStyleForMsgList(Eval("MsgSender").ToString()) %>  MainChatListClass">
                                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# GetPerfactName(Eval("MsgSender").ToString()) %>'></asp:Label>
                                <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ChatMsg") %>'></asp:Label>
                            </div>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:DataList>
                </div>
            </div>
        </asp:Panel>

    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>

<div style="padding: 5px 15px 5px 5px">
    <asp:Panel ID="MsgPanel" runat="server" DefaultButton="sendBTN">
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel3" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <script>
                    function loadingIconVisible() {
                        document.getElementById('<%=LoadingImage.ClientID%>').style.opacity = 1;
                    }
                </script>
                <div>
                    <form runat ="server" >
                         <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager11" runat ="server" ></asp:ScriptManager>
                    <table style="width: 120%">
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="MSGTextBox" runat="server" placeholder="Enter message" CssClass="form-control" Width="100%"></asp:TextBox>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:Button ID="sendBTN" runat="server" Text="Send" OnClick="sendBTN_Click" CssClass="btn btn-default" Width="30%" OnClientClick="loadingIconVisible()" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    <asp:Image ID="LoadingImage" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/loadingIcon.gif" ImageAlign="Right" />
                        </form>
                </div>

            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </asp:Panel>
</div>
<style>
    .SenderClass {
        left: 55%;
        background: #0b59ce;
        color: #ffffff;
        border: 1px solid #0b59ce;
    }

    .ReceiverClass {
        left: -55%;
        background: #c46909;
        color: #ffffff;
        border: 1px solid #c46909;
    }

    .MainChatListClass {
        padding: 5px;
        width: 250px;
        position: relative;
        border-radius: 5px;
        word-wrap: break-word;
        margin-top: 5px;
    }

    .SenderClass::after {
        content: ' ';
        position: absolute;
        width: 0;
        height: 0;
        left: 243px;
        top: 0px;
        border: 10px solid;
        border-color: transparent transparent #0b59ce #0b59ce;
    }

    .ReceiverClass::after {
        content: ' ';
        position: absolute;
        width: 0;
        height: 0;
        right: 243px;
        top: 3px;
        border: 10px solid;
        border-color: #c46909 #c46909 transparent transparent;
    }
</style>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: Yes, you need to include it within a `<form runat="server" />` tag, and you only need one instance of `ScriptManager`

Comment: As the error messages indicate. You cannot use 2 ScriptManager.

Comment: @Napoli sir,if i use single script manager then error remains same

Comment: You probably have a `ScriptManager` on your MasterPage (Site.Master). Check there

Comment: what @zgood said.

Comment: @zgood please can you elaborate it,where i want to place `scriptmanager` in master page ?I want to remove `script manager` from aspx page??

Comment: @icon Normally you would place your `ScriptManager` in your MasterPage inside the `<form runat="server">` since you can only have 1 instance of it. That way its available on every page, so you don't need to put it in your aspx page

Comment: @zgood if i use `scriptManager` inside the master page before `contentplaceholder` and i remove both `scriptmanager` tags from `aspx` page then this error comes `Control 'ScriptManager11' of type 'ScriptManager' must be placed inside a form tag with runat=server.`

Comment: @zgood Unfortunately but i have no form in master page

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `ScriptManagerProxy` (also listed in the toolbox below `ScriptManager`) which does exactly that.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.scriptmanagerproxy(v=vs.110).aspx

From the official documentation (see link above):

> A Web page can contain only one ScriptManager control, either directly
>   on the page or indirectly inside a nested or parent component. The
>   ScriptManagerProxy control lets you add scripts and services to
>   content pages and to user controls if the master page or host page
>   already contains a ScriptManager control.

Comment: @icon Replace `ScriptManager` with `ScriptManagerProxy` in your content page above. You get the error because obviously your *master* page already contains a `ScriptManager`.

Comment: @depant i have put one `scriptmanager` in master page before `contentplaceholder` tag and i put one `scriptmanagerproxy` tag inisde the `<form>` tag but i have still error `Control 'ScriptManager11' of type 'ScriptManager' must be placed inside a form tag with runat=server.`

Answer (score 0):

You have two script managers in the content page.

```
     <asp:ScriptManager runat ="server" ></asp:ScriptManager>
and
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager11" runat ="server" ></asp:ScriptManager>
```

Remove the second one and check. Also check in the master page in case you have any more script manager there.